# android studio do not support c++ function navigation（NOT NDK） when reading android source code?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

Hello all，I download and compile the **android source code** successfully, now I want to use android studio to read the code, I find that the java code function navigation is support, but c/c++ not, can any one help me ?

This is what I have done:

1. ran the script `development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh` successfully, and I got the out file `android.iml` and `android.ipr`
2. ran android studio then import the file `android.ipr`

Comment: Have you found some solution to this ?

Comment: Actually not, so I read the code with emacs...